# Recent apps on wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os

I was wondering if there is some way of enabling recent apps on wear OS or if it exists in the system in the first place. I hate that when I have an app open (Google Keep) when the screen dims, the app closes and i have to find it again in launcher, which is annoying. If not, is it somehow possible to develop an app that launches by pressing rebindable button and shows recent apps? Thanks

My watch: Ticwatch 3 Pro GPS

Wear OS version: 2.38

I tried searching for this kind of problem but didn't find anything

Comment: Galaxy Watch 4 has a "recent apps" app, that shows them in a carousel.  Wear 3 standard UI has them at the top of the launcher. You don't need another app for this.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see i forgot to mention that my watch is on Wear 2.38. I have Ticwatch 3 Pro GPS, is there any way of upgrading to Wear 3 or it's just not possible and I will have to buy newer one when the time comes? Thanks

Comment: You'll have to contact Mobvoi for information about upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after learning, that Wear OS 3 has recent apps from @yuri-schimke, I  searched more with my current watch, and I found out it is promised from Google that it will receive update to Wear 3. As Yuri suggested, i could contact Mobvoi about more exact date when it will happen, but I am happy with knowing it will come someday. For now I will just have to wait :)

I found [this](https://www.techadvisor.com/article/744790/wear-os-3.html) while searching + another article in my native language.